# Django + Celery + SQS - Messages received but not executed by celery worker?

Tags: django, celery, amazon-sqs

I'm trying to implement background tasks on my Django web app using Celery and AWS SQS as the message broker. I have a view which calls a task, which is sent to SQS successfully. In the console window where I have started the Celery worker, I get a statement saying the the task was received. However, the actual task never gets executed (i.e. the print statements I have added in the task never get printed).

I have configured Celery in my `settings.py` -

```
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TASK_DEFAULT_QUEUE = 'tk-test-queue'
CELERY_BROKER_URL = "sqs://%s:%s@" % (quote(os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'), safe=''), quote(os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'), safe=''))
CELERY_BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {
    'region': 'ap-south-1',
    'visibility-timeout': 60 * 30,
    'polling_interval': 1
}
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = None
```

My `celery.py` looks like this -

```
import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'my_project.settings')

app = Celery('my_project')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace="CELERY")
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

I have defined a task in `my_app/tasks.py` -

```
from time import sleep, ctime

from celery import shared_task


@shared_task
def export_report_to_s3():
    print(f'Starting task at {ctime()}')
    sleep(25)
    print(f'Task finished at {ctime()}')
```

Which I am using in my `my_app/views.py` -

```
class TestCeleryView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        print('In view')
        export_report_to_s3.delay()
        return HttpResponse('Success')
```

I am starting the celery worker by running -

```
celery -A my_project worker -l INFO
```

Every time I visit the URL for my view function, I get a Success response from the view, and the number of in-flight requests on SQS goes up. But I get no output by the Celery worker. This is my first time working with Celery as well as SQS. What am I doing wrong?